# Find all functions that satisfy the identity $f(x+5y)+f(x-5y)=2x^2+50y^2$.

Tags: functions

My method goes like this.

Since I found that $2x^2+50y^2=2(x^2+25y^2)$ which can be written as a difference of squares in complex numbers. So I suppose $x+5y=a+bi=z$, so $x-5y=a-bi=\bar z$.

So basically, $f(z)+f(\bar z)=2z\bar z=z\bar z+z\bar z=z\bar z+\bar z\bar {\bar z}$.

So, $f(z)=z\bar z$. In reals, that is $f(x)=x^2$.

Is my method valid? I feel like getting this by luck. Could anyone introduce me a more general method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alan's answer has to be the slickest one possible, but what would you do if you didn't spot that trick? Defining $g(x):=f(x)-x^2$ gives $g(x+5y)+g(x-5y)=0$. Any two values can be written as $x\pm5y$ for some choice of $x,\,y$, so $g$ must always be $0$.

Comment: Well, when solving functional equations, it is quite automatic to try some values like $0,1,-1,2,-2,2^n$ and so on. So I doubt that in the present case $y=0$ would remain unseen.

Comment: @zwim Absolutely. But interestingly, this approach lets us replace $(x+5y,\,x-5y)$ with *any* permutation $h$ of $\Bbb R^2$, even if $y=0$ isn't an interesting case of it, so long as the functional equation is of the form $f(h_1(x,\,y))+f(h_2(x,\,y))=F(h_1(x,\,y))+F(h_2(x,\,y))$ for some obvious function $F$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Set $y = 0$ to obtain $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Plugging this into the functional equation, we see that $f(x) = x^2$ is indeed a solution, and this is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$(A+B)^2+(A-B)^2=2(A^2+B^2)$$ is simpler in this regard.

Comment: $$(A+B)^2+(A-B)^2=2(A^2+B^2)$$